# Incorporating php variable into url with href attribute

Tags: php

I am trying to create the necessary url from this code however it is working and I am struggling to find out why.

```
$linkere = $row['message'];
echo '<a href="me.php?message=<?php echo rawurlencode($linkere); ?>">'
```

Currently this code is producing the url: me.php?message= . But, I would like it to create the url: me.php?message=hello  for example.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have alot of syntax problems here.

first, you need to use Concatenation `message='.rawurlencode($linker).'"`
second your variable do not exist, it should be $linker.

Second close the  tag and insert the text, in this case i used Test.

```
$linker = $row['message'];
echo '<a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linker).'">Test</a>';
```

Comment: So is this ok: '<b><a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linkere);'">' . $row['title']. '</a></b><br>' . $row['message'];

Comment: No, '.rawurlencode($linkere);'" it should be '.rawurlencode($linkere).'" , notice the "." (dot) after $linkhere)

Comment: To continue with what Jorge said, the semicolon in your string escape will end the echo entirely. Use this: `echo '<b><a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linkere).'">' . $row['title']. '</a></b><br>' . $row['message']; `

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `$linkere` to `rawurlencode()`. The variable is actually named `$linker`.

```
$linker = $row['message'];
echo '<a href="me.php?message=<?php echo rawurlencode($linker); ?>">'
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reason - thanks anyway!

Comment: Your answer still contains the syntax errors that are causing the root issue. There are now three duplicate answers to this questions that solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<? ?>` and `echo` in your echo, it should just be:

```
$linkere = $row['message'];
echo '<a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linkere).'">Test</a>';
```

Otherwise you are turning php on and off again to echo something within an already open instance of php in which you are already echoing.

Comment: `code` echo '<br><br><br><br><br><b><a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linkere);'">' . $row['title']. '</a></b><br>' . $row['message'];

Comment: It works for me when I copied and pasted the code back in. I updated the entire section though with your code and more robust link text. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $linker = $row['message'];
 echo '<a href="me.php?message='.rawurlencode($linker).'">YOUR LINK TEXT HERE</a>';
```